# May one have a torah aliyah during the mourning period

Tags: halacha, torah-service, mourning-aveilus

Is it okay to have a torah aliyah during the 11 month mourning period, or should one wait?

Comment: Do you mean the 12 month mourning period (11 month is only for kadish; mourning continues into 12th month for a parent)?

Comment: If you're asked up for an aliyah, you can let the gabbai know that you're in mourning.  They would know the shul's policies and if not, they will ask someone who does.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that there are various customs. Some communities give last aliyah (acharon) to a mourner who then says half Kaddish.

Comment: My mother passed away 8 months ago. Is it best to wait until the mourning period is over before having an aliyah?

Comment: @SteveDorfman, my condolences. Note that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends. Also, since your question seems now to have been whether one should wait (or, to the contrary, may get an _aliya_ during the mourning period), and not whether one may wait (or, to the contrary, should get an _aliya_ during the mourning period), I'm editing the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

[Rivivos Efraim 5:556](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1086&st=&pgnum=438) concludes that although there is no Chiyuv for an Avel during the 12 months to get an Aliya every Shabbos, it is a good idea if possible. Thus it seems clear that an Avel should get an Aliya if possible during the 12 months.